# Error al entrenar modelo randomForest con librería caret

Tags: r

Al entrenar el modelo randomForest mediante la librería caret:

```
set.seed(12345)
ajustes_rf <- trainControl(method='cv',  # validación cruzada
             number = 10)  # diez submuestras
randomForest_caret <- train(income ~ age + marital + race + sex + hr_per_week, 
data = trainData,
      method = 'rf',
      ntree = 500,
      importance = TRUE,
      trControl = ajustes_rf,
      allorParallel = FALSE)
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

*Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
Accuracy       Kappa

Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA

1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA

Median : NA   Median : NA

Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN

3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA

Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA

NA's   :3     NA's   :3

Error: Stopping*

He probado a añadir y cambiar diferentes variables en la función train pero no hay forma. Alguna idea?

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Revisa que no tengas `NA's` en alguna variable.

Comment: Nos puedes compartir un ejemplo del data frame que estas utilizando